# How do I access the redux store from a helper class or function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the access token stored on the Redux store and I want to send it with each API request where authentication is needed. I have a class for API functions. Which is kind of a library. I am not sure how I can access the token from the API class.

Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: Why storing Token in redux store. You must store it in Localstorage or Session Storage and access in your helper class while Sending API request.

Comment: I use Redux Persist to store the user reducer, so it stores the user name and a jwt token.

Comment: But when you refresh page what will happen.

Comment: Redux Persist will keep the user information persistent. i'll get the user information even after refresh.

Comment: So you already got the Answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to import store in the file you need to access the store from your respective index file, i have done it like this

```
import { store } from '../index';

 store.subscribe(() => {
      store.getState();
      token = store.getState().Login.token; //access token here
 })
```

In the index.android.js/index.ios.js i have exported store

```
export const store = createStore(
  RootReducer,
  undefined,
  // the ordering of middleware is significant.
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need have access from your component and considering you have a reducer called user and in your initial state you have something like this:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  logged: false  
}
```

1. import { connect } from 'react-redux'

2. Create your mapStateToProps like:

   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        logged: state.user.logged
      }
   }
3. As a good practice create a prop in your component:

   MyComponent.propTypes = {
      logged: PropTypes.bool
   }